# Memcached PHP module: How can you tell if the connection failed?

Tags: php, memcached

in a php file, I have:

```
<?php
$m = new Memcached();
echo get_class($m);
echo "<br>";
echo $m->addServer('192.168.1.77', 11211, 1);
$m->set("foo", "bar");
?>
```

when run, around a half second later, I get:

```
Memcached
1
```

If I stop memcached, after about 5 seconds, I get:

```
Memcached
1
```

I was expecting something more like...

```
Memcached
0
```

How do you know if you've successfully hit the memcached server or not? I was fully expecting it to be as simple as a return value from addServer... :(

Comment: oh yeah... and does anyone know where the official documentation is for the memcached php-module by the name of "memcached" with the 'd'?  It's so frustrating trying to find the actual documentation when they named it the exact same name as the daemon... ARGH!

Comment: whats the $m->addServer('192.168.1.77', 11211, 1); returns?

Comment: it returns `1` every time.. regardless of whether or not my memcached daemon is running on that IP or not...

Comment: the only difference I've been able to find between a successful connection and a failed connection is that set() will hang the execution until the connection times out.

Comment: Did you flush first? like: start, assign, flush, stop and check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kinda what I was looking for: Memcached::getStats();

So, I wrote:

```
add_memcached_server($m, $addr, $port)
{
    $m->addServer($addr,$port);
    $statuses = $m->getStats();
    return isset($statuses[$addr.":".$port]);
}
```

works like a charm...

Comment: That doesn't work when connecting to a Memcached with SASL without SASL authentication.

Comment: You also need to check for the `pid`, because if a server is added but not connected, it still shows up in the stats, but with `pid=-1`

so I would suggest this:
`return ($statuses[$addr.":".$port]['pid'] > 0);`

Answer (score 1):

Answer is

```
   /**
   * check for connection was established
   * @param resource $m
   * @param string $host
   * @param int $port
   * @access public
   * @return bool
   */
   function memConnected($m, $host, $port = 11211)
   {
      $statuses = $m->getStats();
      return (isset($statuses[$host.":".$port]) and $statuses[$host.":".$port]["pid"] > 0);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it

```
/**
 * Add memcached server
 * @param String $new_ New Memcahed
 * @param String $addr Address
 * @param String $port Port
 * @return boolean
 */
function add_memcached_server($new_, $addr, $port)
{
    $new_->addServer($addr,$port);
    $statuses = $new_->getStats();
    if($statuses[$addr.':'.$port]['uptime']<1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/memcache.addserver states that

> When using this method (as opposed to Memcache::connect() and Memcache::pconnect()) the network connection is not established until actually needed.

so there is no way `addServer` knows if the network connection is established

use http://php.net/memcache.connect instead

Comment: Even though this answer is correct, `connect` cannot be replaced with `addServer`, because the latter is used when you have a pool of several memcached servers

Comment: I'm using `memcached` (as opposed to `memcache` without the `d`)

Comment: connect doesn't exist in the php module called "memcached": http://php.net/memcached.connect